# one page html template into laravel blade

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am use one page html template but how in side my html temaptle only one index.html page. Other all page embeded as section.so the problem is that how to convert that template in laravel.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example so that you can receive help. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the file extension from `.html` to `.blade.php`.

I.e Rename your "HTML template" from `index.html` to `index.blade.php`

To learn more about Laravel Blade sections, check here:

[Extending A Layout](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#extending-a-layout)

> When defining a child view, use the `@extends` Blade directive to
> specify which layout the child view should "inherit". Views which
> extend a Blade layout may inject content into the layout's sections
> using `@section` directives.

Comment: i dot undersand can you more expline

Comment: i will change all and then i go to create the route and the go to index file and set the @extend but how to set the section for it use this one https://technext.github.io/creative-2/#contact

Comment: @HasanAhmedChohan , without showing me some of your source code, what you've tried and failed, I'm unable to discern what you're talking about.